# Lubuntu not connecting after I upgraded to 15.10 from 15.04, using wifi usb adapter

Tags: networking, usb, lubuntu, 15.10

So. I'm currently using Lubuntu 15.10 on an older Dell Dimension 4600 PC. After upgrading from 15.04 yesterday, the usb wifi adapter that I was using to connect stopped connecting. It will just sit there looking for signal and keep bouncing back with the network password screen. It is currently using `kernel 4.2.0-16`.

I found the usb wifi adapter by running the `lsusb` command from the terminal. The results are as follows:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 050d:845a Belkin Components F7D2101 802.11n 
    Surf & Share Wireless Adapter v1000 [Realtek RTL8192SU]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 08e4:013e Pioneer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 046d:c24a Logitech, Inc. G600 Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2516:0011  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0557:7000 ATEN International Co., Ltd Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```